# Tags data-value with separator ' ' (one whitespace) was interpreted as one

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, x-editable

I was trying to use `select2` with `x-editable` to edit tags, for which I override some defaults: set separator to ' ' (default is comma).

I set `data-value="what,no,alright,sha e b r"` that should be actually 4 tags: `what,no,alright,sha` `e` `b` `r`. But it turned out to be one tag `what,no,alright,sha,e,b,r` shown.

Here is the js code: http://jsfiddle.net/MYDJ9/5/

Just let me know if anything need to be clarified. Thanks.

Comment: I think you are using wrong seperator `" "`. you may use `","`.

Comment: I intentionally use " ", because my data-value is space separated. BTW, which place do you suggest to replace with ","?

Answer (score 1):

Got same problem, but i solved this in that way
[issue report at x editable](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/issues/663)
[same subject with x-editable support answer](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/issues/357)
and more info had found at select2 primary developing site
github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues

**oryginally:**

```
separator: ",",
tokenSeparators: [], // this is an array by default is empty, so the separator will be default ",",
```

So If you find this problem in Your app [php or other programmers]

**change the delimeter as You need to:**

```
separator: "|",
need to give tokenSeparators:["|", " "],
```

Or any other that You need.Cheers